# Prevent deleting entry from array c#

Tags: c#, arrays

I have two arrays of strings and the problem is, that `resvalues` contains one string of pk two times. Even though the loop just runs one time, both entries of `resvalues` were deleted.

```
      for (int i = 0; i < pk.Length; i++)
        {
            if (columnname[i] == pk[i])
            {
                columnname = columnname.Where(w => w != columnname[i]).ToArray();
                resvalues = resvalues.Where(w => w != resvalues[i]).ToArray();
            }
        }
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: `columname` and `resvalues` should have the same length...

Comment: If you are trying to remove duplicates, you could use resvalues.Distinct()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line : `resvalues = resvalues.Where(w => w != resvalues[i]).ToArray();` executes every time there is a match in your if clause.

So, even though the match only happens once (I presume), the code executed finds and moves the items to resvalues which are different from w. That is why both values get deleted.

Comment: @NickS. - instead of using the line of code which you used, just delete the specific element you want to. I suggest you use lists instead of arrays and that will make your life simpler in regards to deleting a specific element. You could do the following: ```var resvaluesList= new List<YourType>(resvalues);
resvaluesList.RemoveAt(i);
resvaluesList.ToArray()```

Comment: `var resvaluesList = new List<string>(resValues);` I get a syntax error?

Comment: sorry, I'm new at using lists :)

Answer (score 0):

If the values in `columnname` and the values in `resvalues` need to be kept "in sync", it strongly suggests that you should be grouping those values into an *object* of some sort and working with a single collection/array of those objects instead.

E.g. if they're both `string` then introduce a new `class`:

```
public class ColumnAndRes {
    public string ColumnName {get;set;}
    public string ResValue {get;set;}
}
```

(This is a fairly anaemic class, you can definitely do more to make this *better*).

Then, however you're currently populating columnname and resvalues, you instead create new instances of the above class and store those instead.

(What you're currently doing is sometimes referred to as "Array Oriented Programming" or ["Parallel Collections"](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/06/03/anti-pattern-parallel-collections/), and is usually frowned upon)